# How would I identify the type of paper being used in a folded origami?

Tags: paper, origami

If I was looking at a piece of origami on display or somewhere where I cannot feel it, how could I identify the type of paper being used? I do not need specifics.

Comment: _I do not need specifics._ Do you have a list of criteria you would base this answer on? I have never done any real analysis on paper before. Another way to phrase this would be "How can I recognize types of paper?" which is a poor question by  the way. I imagine there are many types of paper however are only a small subset are _generally_ found in origami? You can fold almost any paper you would want. It is dependent on what you want it to look like I suppose. My point is I think you need to try and narrow down this question somehow. I will have to do some research before I can suggest how.

Comment: I do think from [your meta post](http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/q/129/44) that `paper` would be a better fit then `tool-identification`

Comment: I think the actual best option is to ask the author of the origami.

Comment: @SF, although in origami there are folders and there are designers, just as there are musicians and composers.  The "author"/designer may not be the folder.

Comment: @inkista: I believe both author of the design (designer), and the author of the finished piece (folder) would be able to help. It's not like the designers invent that in their heads never creating actual folded paper figurines of their designs.

Comment: @SF. Except that the question is about IDing the paper from looking at a model. No designer can know which papers the thousands of possible folders may or may not have used if s/he wasn't the only folder. Also some designers, like Eric Joisel, sadly aren't with us any more.

Comment: @inkista: If you want *a good paper for that model* then asking any will work. If you want *that specific paper* then you must ask the folder.

Comment: @SF. Agreed. But the question was about IDing _that specific paper_, not one good for the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much can't, unless it's specifically listed in the description of the piece.  The sheer variety of papers used worldwide, and the fact that some creators, like Michael LaFosse, *make their own paper* specifically for the model they're folding, means that your chances of accurately identifying the paper used is going to be very very tough, especially if you can't judge the thickness, sizing, or the fiber content by touch.

That said, the appearance of some papers is very characteristic, and if you have experience with kami, elephant hide, Canson watercolor paper, various craft papers, tissue foil, etc., some of those may be self-evident. Every origami folder tends to be intimately familiar with kami (so-called "origami paper") and can usually identify it on sight both from appearance and usage.

Characteristics of the paper that *might* lead to identification would be the surface texture being shiny or matte (surface [sizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizing)), fiber appearance/color, thickness/weight, and, of course, the size.